# Is there no built in way to get a table's schema in ADO.NET?

Tags: ado.net, c#-4.0

I want to get a table's schema in order.  [This question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/173834/456188) is exactly my question, and what I want to do. However it feels (to me) pretty hackish, and being two years old now I was hoping that the answer was out-of-date.  Is there truly still no way to get a table's schema in its native order? (e.g. ADOX's `OpenSchema(adSchemaTables...)`)?

Subjective side-question: is this not a huge gaping hole in ADO.NET in general!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
exec sp_help '<tablename>'
```

or

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = '<tablename>' order by ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Comment: Ok, that seems much more like it.  At least it's cleaner than GetSchema

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GetSchema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254934.aspx) on the Connection object.

Comment: GetSchema returns the columns in an arbitrary order (arbitrary, at least, as far as I can tell), but certainly not in the order you'd see them in Sql Management Studio, or the like.

Comment: You don't get them in order in ODBC or JDBC either. There's no obligation on provider or driver writers to return them in order.

Comment: I just realized that I figured out how to get it right:  you can use Select on the result with "TABLE_TYPE DESC" etc. passed in, to order it whatever way you like.