# Oracle SQL: How to get the list of columns/fields for any given query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to know the list of columns for any given query, how can we do that? The query can be something like...

```
select * from some_tab1  (should return all the column names in some_tab1)
select col1, col2, col3 from some_tab2  (should return col1, col2, col3)
select col1 as 1, col2 as 2 from some_tab3  (should return 1, 2)
```

I know how we can get the list of columns for a given table but is there a way to get the list of columns for a given query, regardless of if there's data or not?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It can be done but it depends on the environment. In what environment will you need to know the query columns (PL/SQL, Java program, C# program etc.)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're doing. You have the query as a string, and you want to parse it to get the result set's column list? Have you looked at `dbms_sql`?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're not trying to find the columns accessed by a query that is held in an application of some sort (like peoplesoft query), right?

Comment: You can use `dbms_sql.describe_columns` in PL/SQL to get this information. Otherwise your programming language will have things for that (e.g. JDBC's `ResultSetMetaData`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with...

dbms_sql.describe_columns3(dbms_sql.to_cursor_number(rc), count, tab);

where rc is the ref cursor to the sql. count is output param that returns the column count and tab is the actual output collection.

Thanks to @Alex Poole and @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1):

Oracle's DESCRIBE command doesn't support that. The closest I think you can get (without writing a custom command), is to either fetch 1 record from the query with a high level host language, then iterate the resulting columns, or to create a view or temp table from the query and describe that. The latter would be something like:

```
create table t$$desc as 
   select * from some_tab1  (should return all the column names in some_tab1)
   where 1 = 0
;

desc t$$desc
```

If you use JDBC or ADO or some other host language you can fetch the "schema" of a query. Things like DataReader support a .GetSchema() method that returns an object describing the schema of the result set. A sample is here: [Get the schema for a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173834/ado-net-getting-the-schema-for-a-table)